# Cool Edit Pro alternative for Mac?

Tags: software, mac

I just can't find a program similar to Cool Edit Pro for the Mac. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cool Edit Pro is now Adobe Audition. They have started a beta, so you're in luck.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/audition/

Comment: As a side note: Audition is, in my opinion, much worse than CEP. If the OP really likes CEP, they might not find Audition a reasonable substitute.

Comment: @Sklivvz: exactly what I was going to write :)

Comment: It is miles and miles ahead of Soundbooth, though.

Comment: +1 and it's now officially released as Adobe Audition CS5.5 for both Mac and PC. I use it on both platforms and they work pretty much the same. Also, if you have old Cool Edit Pro / Audition .ses files, you will need to get them converted to the new XML-based .sesx format using the following cheap third party tool: http://www.aatranslator.com.au/ses2sesx.html

Comment: @Sklivvz - why do you think Audition is worse than Cool Edit Pro (CEP)? I have used both. Though I have to say that some of the great features in Audition have been in the software for years, including in CEP: such as the multi-track, non-destructive editor, the envelopes, the timeshifting, the noise reduction. I'm still learning with CS5.5 so maybe I'll see what benefits it brings.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the functionality needed, [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) (it's free) may do the trick.  Otherwise, you might try [Cubase](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/start.html) (it's expensive depending on version).

Both can use your existing sound interface.  If you want an easier (in my opinion) user interface, check into [ProTools](http://www.avid.com/us/products/family/pro-tools), but you will need to buy compatible hardware.

Comment: I tried Audacity a while ago, but I really don't like the interface. As for Cubase and Pro Tools, aren't they too 'big' to be compared to CEP? I need an application focused on audio editing only, easy to use and with a relatively simple interface - like CEP basically. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: See my answer [here](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/looking-for-an-sound-editor-for-mac-osx/1385#1385) for info on Reaper.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow Cool Edit user, I recently started doing some basic single track recording on Mac.  The best app I've come across so far has been Sound Studio by Felt Tip Inc http://felttip.com/ss/ (You'll need the older version created by FreeVerse for older versions of OSX).  I'm planning to experiment with some other apps listed here: http://www.pure-mac.com/audio.html but will most likely purchase Felt Tip, as so far, it has served me well.